# Very slowly converging power series without a closed form value

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, power-series

Suppose , $$\sum_{s=0}^{\infty} a_sx^s$$

is a convergent power series, but very slowly converging. In the case, the power series has a closed form, this is no problem,

$$\sum_{s=0}^\infty 0.999999^s$$ can easily be calculated because of $$\sum_{s=0}^\infty x^s=\frac{1}{1-x}$$ for $-1<x<1$.

But what, if we do not have such a closed form ?

> Is it always possible to find the limit with reasonable accuracy, even if the series converges awfully slowly ?
>
> Or can it be very difficult (or even infeasible in practice) to calculate the sum ?

We can assume that the sum is small enough for a computer program to handle it. (Of course, the value could be somewhere near $10^{10^{100}}$).

I know that there are methods to accelerate the convergence, but can we be sure that they actually give a result near the actual limit ?

Comment: Naively (with the existing constraints of the question) "no": Computation is (very loosely) a countable matter, while the vector space of convergent series is uncountably infinite-dimensional. That said, do you have a particular form in mind for the coefficients $a_{n}$, e.g., they're given by an algebraic formula (or at least generated by some algorithm)? Are you assuming the coefficients are positive? Monotone decreasing...?

Comment: To give a concrete example : What is $$\sum_{s=1}^{\infty} 0.999999^s\ln(s)$$ ?

Comment: PARI/GP says : $13238288.69285260097048719748$

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang We can assume that the $a_s$ can easily be calculated.

Comment: Well since there are uncountably many values, I'd say you cannot find closed form for all of them.  Even if you stick to algebraic $x$, there won't be closed forms for all of them, but you can approximate any of them to as many places as you want

Comment: The coefficients in your example are positive and eventually decreasing. :) The larger point of my first comment is, if you hope for a definitive answer, I think you'll need to be more precise (perhaps meticulously so) about the properties of the $a_{n}$ that you're willing to assume.

Comment: For many series related with the irrationality measure of pi convergence is unknown, and even if they are converging regardless of our inability to prove it, convergence is so slow that usual acceleration techniques are not effective. So, for short: no. But obviously we should define better what reasonable accuracy really means.

Comment: Does anyone know what the polylog-syntax in mathworld is ? I could not find it out. Here , the is the sum and the result  : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(s%3D1,infinity,x%5Es*log(s))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use series acceleration techniques, like Wynn's epsilon method for linearly convergent series or even accelerate logarithmicaly convergent series. These methods can also give error estimators, which can be used to construct reliable stopping rules.

You may look at
Weniger, Ernst Joachim. "Nonlinear sequence transformations for the acceleration of convergence and the summation of divergent series." Computer Physics Reports 10.5-6 (1989): 189-371. This paper analyses different algorithms and provide error analysis.

Comment: But I guess that given an acceleration technique, there is some series whose convergence is not improved at all by that technique, i.e. there is no universal acceleration method, just like there is no universal compression scheme.

Comment: For instance, how to accelerate $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\tan n}{n^4},$$ assuming it is convergent?

Comment: No, any method works only for some class of problems. For example Wynn's epsilon method works only for linearly convergent series, the Levin's sequence transformation works for logarithmicaly convergent series satisfying $s_n = s + n^{-\alpha}(b + O(n^{-1}))$ for $b\neq 0$ and $\alpha > 0$, where $s_n$ is the sequence of partial sums.